# Can't allow my JavaWebStart auto-signed application in my java security list

Tags: java, heroku, parse-platform, applet, java-web-start

I have a JavaWebStart application which is self-signed.
My JavaWebStart application was downloadable on a Parse.com server, I just added http://myapp.parseapp.com to my Java security list and all worked fine.

Since Parse.com announce they will close their service, I have migrated my app to "Heroku".

But now, my link is like https://myapp.herokuapp.com, and when I try to add this link to my Java security list, my JavaWebStart application can't be allowed started...

Here is my old JNLP file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase=
"http://myapp.parseapp.com/templates" 
    href="TVRFID.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Test</title>
        <vendor>Moi</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
        <icon href="icon.gif"/>
        <shortcut>
            <desktop/>
        </shortcut>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.8+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="applet.jar"
            main="true" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc
         name="Test"
         main-class=
           "vmp.Main"
         width="1280"
         height="768">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Here is my new JNLP file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase=
"https://myapp.herokuapp.com/public/templates" 
    href="TVRFID.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Test</title>
        <vendor>Moi</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
        <icon href="icon.gif"/>
        <shortcut>
            <desktop/>
        </shortcut>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.8+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="applet.jar"
            main="true" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc
         name="Test"
         main-class=
           "vmp.Main"
         width="1280"
         height="768">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Thanks in advance for any idea to solve this problem...

Comment: *"Can't allow my JavaWebStart auto-signed application in my java security list"* That's a 'feature' not a bug. Since the app. needs to be signed with a valid certificate to have a hope of working for random strangers on the net, might as well get the certificate and start doing that right now.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the `MANIFEST.MF`, I forgot to change the link in it, so now it work and my `MANIFEST.MF` look like :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: https://myapp.herokuapp.com/public/templates
Application-Name: MYAPP
Main-Class: vmp.Main
```